# Как отобразить элемент полностью, не скрывая его за областью блока?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

В данном случае при нажатии на чекбокс, кнопка "Применить" должна отображаться полностью.

Ставил `overflow: visible;` а так же `z-index:9999;`, но не пойму в чем проблема, почему она все равно показывается не полностью.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var _history = [];

  $('.ctf--b-filt-check-list :checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var c = $(this).prop('checked');
    var filterId = $(this).find('input:checked').context.id;

    if (!c) {
      delHistory(filterId);
      if ($('.' + filterId + '').css('display') != 'none') {
        $('.' + _history[0] + '').show(300);
      }
      $('.' + filterId + '').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
      _history.unshift(filterId);
      $('.ctf--b-filt-check-list span').css('display', 'none');
      $('.' + filterId + '').show(300);
    }
  });

  function delHistory(elem) {
    var index = _history.indexOf(elem);
    if (index > -1) {
      _history.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };
});
```

```css
/* vertical scroll-bar */
.ctf--c-scroll { height:500px; overflow:hidden; position:relative; margin:10px -5px 10px 0; }
.ctf--b-filt-c-item .jspContainer { overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
.ctf--b-filt-c-item .jspPane { width:100% !important; margin-left:0 !important; position:absolute; top:0; left:0 !important; box-sizing:border-box; }
.ctf--b-filt-c-item .jspVerticalBar { right:0 !important; top:0; position:absolute; height:100%; width:9px; cursor:pointer; }
.ctf--b-filt-c-item .jspTrack { right:0 !important; width:9px; position:relative; background-color:#eaeaea; box-sizing:border-box; height:100%; border-radius:2px; }
.ctf--b-filt-c-item .jspDrag { width:7px !important; border-radius:3px; left:0; margin: 1px; top:0; position:absolute; cursor:pointer; background:#c6c6c6; }

.design {
  margin-top:-17px;
  margin-left:15px;
  z-index:9999;
  overflow:visible;
  background-color: #ededed;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  padding:10px;
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
  border-radius: 15px;
  visibility: visible;
}

.design::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%; /* To the left of the tooltip */
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #ededed transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ctf--b-filt-c-body" style="display: block;">
                            <div class="ctf--b-wpr-scr ctf--c-scroll jspScrollable" tabindex="0" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 193px;">
              
          <div class="jspContainer" style="width: 193px; height: 500px;"><div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 180px;"><ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list ">
                  <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_2" checked="" value="13659">
                    <label for="idchkk_2_1_2">
                      <i></i>
                      BOSCH
                    </label>
                    <span style="display: none;" class="design idchkk_2_1_2"><button type="submit" class="ctf-b-btn-aply">Применить</button></span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_11" value="13760">
                    <label for="idchkk_2_1_11">
                      <i></i>
                      FURUKAWA BATTERY
                    </label>
                    <span style="display: none;" class="design idchkk_2_1_11"><button type="submit" class="ctf-b-btn-aply">Применить</button></span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_14" value="13823">
                    <label for="idchkk_2_1_14">
                      <i></i>
                      HANKOOK
                    </label>
                    <span style="display: none;" class="design idchkk_2_1_14"><button type="submit" class="ctf-b-btn-aply">Применить</button></span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_25" value="13727">
                    <label for="idchkk_2_1_25">
                      <i></i>
                      TAB POLAR
                    </label>
                    <span style="display: none;" class="design idchkk_2_1_25"><button type="submit" class="ctf-b-btn-aply">Применить</button></span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_26" value="13725">
                    <label for="idchkk_2_1_26">
                      <i></i>
                      TOPLA
                    </label>
                    <span style="display: none;" class="design idchkk_2_1_26"><button type="submit" class="ctf-b-btn-aply">Применить</button></span>
                  </li>
                  
              </ul></div>
              </div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ты же сам ограничил размер блока, в котором у тебя все выводится

```
style="width: 193px;"
```

1) убрать ширину блока или ограничить ее через свойства `min-height`, `max-height`

2) я приводил пример (https://jsfiddle.net/j1wxwjfb/) - сделай одну кнопку "применить", чтобы она была не дочерней для твоего блока с заданной шириной и размещать ее динамически

3) с помощью jquery просто увеличивать размер твоего блока в зависимости от размера кнопки

1 и 2 методы мне кажутся наиболее предпочтительными

Comment: на счет первого варианта: тогда блок будет увеличиваться/уменьшаться, в зависимости от ширины?
на счет второго варианта: хотел воспользоваться вашим вариантом, но не кнопка отображалась где-то в стороне, не смог привязать ее к чекбоксу. это можно исправить?

Comment: на счет первого варианта - именно так - когда невидимый элемент станет видимым - ширина блока увеличится

на счёт второго варианта - вы можете оформить свой код в jsfiddle.net например или в виде файлика куда-нибудь выложить, я бы тогда протестировал и попробовал бы найти решение

Comment: Приблизительно так https://jsfiddle.net/j1wxwjfb/1/ по факту получилось

Comment: Дмитрий, посмотри https://jsfiddle.net/j1wxwjfb/2/

Во-первых у тебя было 2 элемента с одинаковым ID - это не очень хорошо, во-вторых у тебя очень много тегов, лишних тегов - попробуй подчистить, например <div><span>TITLE</span></div> - тут можно одним div обойтись и определить в нем нужные стили. Теперь по самому примеру - я центрую кнопку по вертикали, для этого мне надо знать размер кнопки (я его в стиле установил), но поскольку кнопка может быть невидимой, а в формуле ее высота присутствует, то я его прописываю вручную (не стал искать можно ли получать актуальные размеры невидимых)

Comment: а выравниваю по горизонтали кнопку просто зная ширину твоего блока (ты его сам написал)

хотя понимаю, что это не очень хорошо и лучше все делать автоматически, но для этого предварительно лучше теги подчистить - уж очень их много

Comment: а могли бы подсказать как это кнопку в tooltip засунуть?

Comment: я так понимаю как раз в `span` нужно обернуть, и задать класс

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69442/discussion-between-zhihar-and-dmitriy).

Answer (score 1):

Уважаемый, у вас в html в блоке с классом **ctf--b-wpr-scr ctf--c-scroll jspScrollable** стоит фиксированная ширина 193px.

Увеличьте ее и кнопка появится полностью)

Comment: а поверх блока реально сделать?

Comment: нереально - при одном размере дочерний элемент никогда не будет выше родительского, как бы ты ни игрался с z-index (z-index вообще хитро работает), максимом можно position: fixed сделать, но тогда он закрепится на экране и при движении (прокрутке) страницы твоя кнопка останется на месте, а список убежит